# Can "git log" show branches only (not the intermediate commits)?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'd like to be able to see the relationship between all my branches.

Git log is a beautiful thing:

```
git log --graph --all --format=oneline
```

The output it produces is quite verbose (since I tend to make a lot of small commits on each branch).  What I am looking for is a way to show only the commits that correspond to the head of a branch (just the branch name without the commit summary is fine)

Are there flags to `git log` or another `git` command for this?

Comment: git branch --list

Comment: After a bit of poking around, I found the "Simple History" checkbox in gitk.  I'd like something like this, but on the terminal.  `git branch --list` doesn't show the relationships between branches.

Comment: @MattDeeds What do you mean by "relationships between branches"? Branches are standalone; they don't relate to one another.

Comment: @Jubobs, he probably needs fork and merge history and graph of it.

Comment: @Jubobs, I am talking about the upstream / downstream relationship.  This is indicated by lines in `gitk` or `git log --graph`.  @0andriy, yes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're after the `--no-walk` option. (also `--branches` instead of `--all`, I'd guess).

From comments, you want the output gitk's "simple history" produces.  Gitk uses `--simplify-by-decoration` to get that.

Comment: Actually, it's the graph that I want, just not the interstitial commits.

Comment: A graph of what? A branch tip is a particular commit. Do you want every commit with a branch ref or multiple children?

Comment: Yes.  Every commit with a branch tip or multiple children.  Just like `gitk --all`; View->Edit View->Simple history. Tagged commits would be a nice option.

Comment: Okay. gitk uses `--simplify-by-decoration` to get that.

Comment: Thank you.  What I want is basically this: `git log --graph --all --format=oneline --simplify-by-decoration`